# Zynq block design : beginner's questions

Tags: spi, vivado, zynq

I am a beginner and trying to create a  zynq block design using ZedBoard. I have added Zynq from IP catalogue and run it using Designer Assistance + connect two port (M_AXI_GPO_ACLK and FCLK_CLKO):

[image]

**Questions:**

1. I used before MiniZed and I hadn't M_AXI_GPO_ACLK and FCLK_CLKO ports. *Why do they appear here?*

2.  I have 3 additional port: TTCO_WAVE0_OUT, TTCO_WAVE1_OUT and TTCO_WAVE2_OUT. I can assume they belong to one process. *What is the process?*

3. I will test SPI Controller and integrate SPI1 controller. If I build the zynq-7000 minimum system, I will not be able to use "spips.h"- driver. I read I need to "...select the SPI controller to lead the IO of the SPI interface in the way of EMIO, and then short-circuit the SPI0_MOSI and SPI0_MISO loops on the development board, so that the loopback test can be performed."

*What does it mean "select the SPI controller to lead the IO of the SPI interface in the way of EMIO"?* If I double click, the following window is appeared:
[image]

[MIO configuration]->[I/O Peripherals]-> add SPI1. I will get an additional port SPI_1

*What does "short-circuit the SPI0_MOSI and SPI0_MISO loops on the development board" mean? Make external?*

[image]

The block has more than 1 sub-port ... . *Should all of them be used?*
[image]

4. The current block design:
   [image]

If i generate a bitstream, I will get the following errors:

> [DRC NSTD-1] Unspecified I/O Standard: 4 out of 134 logical ports use
> I/O standard (IOSTANDARD) value 'DEFAULT',instead of a user assigned
> specific value. This may cause I/O contention or incompatibility with
> the board power or  connectivity affecting performance, signal
> integrity or in extreme cases cause damage to the device or the
> components to which it is connected. To correct this violation,
> specify all I/O standards. This design will fail to generate a
> bitstream unless all logical ports have a user specified I/O standard
> value defined. To allow bitstream creation with unspecified I/O
> standard values (not recommended), use this command: set_property
> SEVERITY {Warning} [get_drc_checks NSTD-1].  NOTE: When using the
> Vivado Runs infrastructure (e.g. launch_runs Tcl command), add this
> command to a .tcl file and add that  file as a pre-hook for
> write_bitstream step for the implementation run. Problem ports:
> SPI1_MISO_O_0, SPI1_MOSI_I_0, SPI1_SCLK_I_0, and SPI1_SS_I_0.

> [DRC UCIO-1] Unconstrained Logical Port: 4 out of 134 logical ports
> have no user assigned specific location constraint (LOC). This may
> cause I/O contention or incompatibility with the board power or
> connectivity affecting performance, signal integrity or in extreme
> cases cause damage to the device or the components to which it is
> connected. To correct this violation, specify all pin locations. This
> design will fail to generate a bitstream unless all logical ports have
> a user specified site LOC constraint defined.  To allow bitstream
> creation with unspecified pin locations (not recommended), use this
> command: set_property SEVERITY {Warning} [get_drc_checks UCIO-1].
> NOTE: When using the Vivado Runs infrastructure (e.g. launch_runs Tcl
> command), add this command to a .tcl file and add that file as a
> pre-hook for write_bitstream step for the implementation run.  Problem
> ports: SPI1_MISO_O_0, SPI1_MOSI_I_0, SPI1_SCLK_I_0, and SPI1_SS_I_0.

I tried to fix them via tcl concole:

```
set_property SEVERITY {Warning} [get_drc_checks NSTD-1]
set_property SEVERITY {Warning} [get_drc_checks UCIO-1]
```

It doesnt help me to fix a problem.

I have found a [tutorial "The use of SPI of ZYNQ learning"](https://www.programmersought.com/article/68497188325/). The block design was implemented as I did. I would like to try this way...probably it will solve my issue.

*How to find pins for posts SPI_CLK, SPI_SS. MOSI and MISO ?*

I have a schematic design of ZedBoard. I am not sure which one I have to use, because I didn't use SPI Quard block...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: *Needs more focus - This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*

Comment: Whoof.  There is a lot to process here.  Maybe you would be better served by focussing questions on one topic and fleshing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The Zynq family is a FPGA SoC which includes a "normal" Xilinx FPGA (referred as Programmable Logic or "PL" in the documentation) togheter with a full fledged ARM SoC (Processing System or "PS").
I would suggest you to take a peek at least a the [reference manual](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf) and maybe the [Zynq Book](http://www.zynqbook.com/) free for download.

To answer your questions:

1. FCLK_CLKO is just an output clock from one of the processor PLL. It's one of the few PS to PL clocks channels available.
2. They are outputs from the TTC (Triple Timer Counter) internal to the PS. They can be useful for example to generate PWM signals.
3. The Zynq has 2 SPI controllers, you can use the MIO/EMIO to either route their signals to external pins of the SoC controlled by the PS, or to route them to the PL logic (fpga logic). The tutorial is telling you to take the controller SPI0 and route its signals to the FPGA logic (EMIO).

   After expanding the new SPI port in the block design you can recognize the 3 SPI signals: MOSI, MISO and chip select SS*.
4. As you can see you would need to assigned them to some programmable pin, but in your case you just want to do an internal loopback test. Don't define the pins as external, just connect the MOSI to the MISO. Otherwise you probably want to leave the SPI connected to the MIO (i.e. without passing by the PL), so that the controller will communicate to the dedicated pins of the PS shown in the board schematics.